# Why does DbFunctions not work with Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, linq

```
var vals = (from r in result
                    group r by DbFunctions.TruncateTime(r.Created) into g
                    select new { count = g.Count(), date = g});
```

When I try to run the above I get the following error

`Results` is the result of a DB query

> "This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities."

The model (`result`) returns Dates (amongst other things), all I'm trying to do is group by the date (`created`) and work out how many times it existed.

`Created` is already DateTime

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @spender, I'm already doing what that posts suggests. I also get a different error message to that post, so the question is different

Comment: @spender That post is talking about using `DbFunctions` in a different version of EF.  This question is a bout using `DbFunctions` in Linq-to-objects, which is not possible.

Comment: Yep. I was just about to reopen, but you beat me to it. Apologies to you both.

Comment: @spender, thank you for reading our feedback and taking action. It's great to know the system works and mods are cool to read, review and take appropriate action

Comment: @spender No worries - I just hate it when someone reverses an action I've made without explaining _why_ :)

Comment: Are you in fact using Linq to Entities (ie entity framework) or are you using Linq to Objects (ie IEnumerables)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of the [`DbFunctions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.aspx) class is to convert expressions to the proper SQL syntax:

> Provides common language runtime (CLR) methods that expose EDM canonical functions for use in DbContext or ObjectContext LINQ to Entities queries.

Since you aren't querying a SQL source, there's no reason to use the `DbFunctions` methods.

The equivalent Linq-to-object query would be:

```
var vals = (from r in result
            group r by r.Created.Date into g
            select new { v = g.Count(), d = g});
```

> The issue may be that Created is `DateTime?`

You can account for that with the conditional operator:

```
var vals = (from r in result
            group r by r.Created.HasValue ? (DateTime?)r.Created.Value.Date
                                          : (DateTime?)null 
                into g
            select new { v = g.Count(), d = g});
```

or just

```
var vals = (from r in result
            group r by r.Created.Value.Date into g
            select new { v = g.Count(), d = g});
```

if there's no possibility that `Created` is null (or if you want to throw an exception if it is)

Comment: The `TruncateTime` function generates SQL that strips off the time portion of a `DATETIME` expression.  The `Date` property of `DateTime` does the same thing for .NET `DateTime` values.

Comment: When I try this, it won't compile. The issue may be that Created is DateTime? (accepts nulls)

Comment: This *is* right.. as it's nullable, I need to add `.Value` (as I knew it was populated for this query)